# Using static methods

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a matrix with a static method and I return a new constructor with the built matrix, but whenever I try to get the matrix values, it all ends up being empty.

```
public class KeyTable {

    private char[][] key;
    final static int rows = 5;
    final static int columns = 5;

    public KeyTable(char[][] key) {
        this.key = key;

    }
    public static KeyTable buildFromString(String keyPhrase)
    {
        char[][] alpha = new char[5][5];
        char[] alphabet = "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
        int followingAlphabet = 0;
        for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < columns; c++)
            {
                if(followingAlphabet <= keyPhrase.length()-1)
                    alpha[r][c] = keyPhrase.charAt(followingAlphabet);
                else
                    alpha[r][c] = alphabet[followingAlphabet];
                followingAlphabet++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(alpha));
        return new KeyTable(alpha);
    }

    public char[][] getKeyTable()
    {
        return this.key;
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
package com.company;


import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] alpha = new char[5][5];
        KeyTable key = new KeyTable(alpha);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(alpha));
        KeyTable.buildFromString("EXAMPLE");
        key.getKeyTable();
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(alpha));
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(key.getKeyTable()));

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect your array to contain, and why?

Comment: Note that you completely ignore the value returned by KeyTable.buildFromString("EXAMPLE");

Comment: Start your program with a debugger and step through your code. Then you can monitor objects that are created and check if the values you expect to be assigned are stored somewhere. Set a breakpoint at KeyTable.buildFromString(...) and try to find where the returned object goes and monitor the object `key`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you did two separate things. First you created a KeyTable object with your array. Then you ran a bunch of other random stuff (buildfromString method). Then you ask it to return an empty key and print it. I have no clue what you are actually trying to do but it definitely won't print anything because you didn't store it anywhere. You also have it returning an empty object which makes no sense either. Something like this:

```
key=KeyTable.buildFromString("Example");
```

You then can return you results in your main application to display the information properly. I hope that this helps you. If you provide more details on what you are actually trying to do, I can help more on that.